# SQL Server Copy Database Wizard Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, object-reference, copy-database-wizard

Trying to copy a database using Copy Database Wizard, using drop/re-attach method and getting this error.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

> OnInformation,SQLSERVER2017,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_AVP_SQLSERVER2017_2,{44AD0789-418F-4C5E-BE71-587407A7F9A2},{CA7C84F2-2DD7-4878-9407-85A2E05C093C},3/22/2019
> 9:11:46 PM,3/22/2019 9:11:46 PM,0,0x,Copying file
> \AVP\C$_DB\MyDB_meta.mdf to C:\DB\DATA\MyDB_meta.mdf
> overwrite set to False
>
> OnError,SQLSERVER2017,NT
> Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,AVP_SQLSERVER2017_Transfer Objects
> Task,{309A0DE4-3854-43EF-A7B7-9826AC31C363},{CA7C84F2-2DD7-4878-9407-85A2E05C093C},3/22/2019
> 9:11:46 PM,3/22/2019 9:11:46 PM,0,0x,Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Kindly check your database version . Required both database version is same for copy Database Wizard.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. According Microsoft's documentation versions can be different as long as you're upgrading, moving to a later version is fine, but not to an earlier version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017 - I was attempting to move from 14.0.2002.14 to 14.0.1000.169. Will upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: Update: tried updating versions of the server, still experiencing the same issue, must be something else.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?